# Bernoulli distribution on i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $(X_n)$ be an independent and identically distributed sequence of random variables with distribution Bernoulli of parameter $p$, this is $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = p$, $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 0) = (1−p)$. Set $T_0 = 0$ and for all $n\ge1$, define recursively
> $T_n :=\inf\{k>T_{n−1} :X_k =1\}$.
>
> 1. Show that the random variables $T_1, T_2 − T_1,..., T_n − T_{n−1}$ are independent and identically distributed.
> 2. Compute the generating function of $T_1$, and deduce the generating function of $T_n$.

My attempt: First is it right that $\mathbb{P}(T_1 = k) = p(1 − p)^k$ for $k\ge0$?. In this case we would have that

$\mathbb{P}(T_2−T_1=k)=\mathbb{P}(T_2=k+T_1)=\sum^\infty_{j=0}\mathbb{P}(T_2=k+j,T_1 =j)
=\sum^\infty_{j=0}p(1−p)^kp(1−p)^j =p(1−p)^k$

Then: $\mathbb{P}(T_2−T_1=k,T_1 =j)=\mathbb{P}(T_2=k+j,T_1 =j)=p(1−p)^kp(1−p)^j$
which shows that these random variables are independent.
Does this suffices to say that all $T_i, i=1,...,n$, are independent iteratively? Or do I have to do a (I would say complicated) rigorous proof by induction?

For point 2) first I'm not sure I got the right probability in the first part. Can anyone tell me something please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach for 1) is correct but you will have to handle $T_1,T_2-T_1,...,T_n-T_{n-1}$ in a similar fashion.

Note that $T_1=\inf \{k >0: X_k=1\}=\inf \{k \geq 1: X_k=1\}$. So the correct pmf of $T_1$ is given by $P(T_1=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$ for $k \geq 1$. Hence, $Es^{T_1}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}s^{k} p(1-p)^{k-1}$. This is a geometric series with common ratio $(1-p)s$. Can you write down the sum?

Finally, $Es^{T_n}=Es^{T_1+(T_2-T_1)+\cdots+ (T_n-T_{n-1})}=E(e^{T_1})^{n}$.